# "Could not open input file" error while running php command in windows

Tags: magento2, cli, windows

I have installed `Magento 2.2.5` on my localhost windows system. I use the wamp server.
I am unable to run any PHP command and getting the error `Could not open input file: C:\wamp64\www\magento2`

I got this

```
C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.32>php  C:\wamp64\www\magento2 cache:flush
Could not open input file: C:\wamp64\www\magento2
```

I gave all permissions on the magento2 folder using system property still it doesn't work.
Please suggest me a way out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are running and using the command in the wrong way that's why you are getting the error.

Do this instead:

- First, open `cmd` go to `C:\wamp64\www\magento2` ( I suppose this is your magento2 installation directory)
- From there, run the following commands below and check if you still get the errors you get before

  - **`php bin/magento cache:flush`**

Comment: Thank you for your response.
using your recommended one,I got this  " 'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file"
C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.32 - this the place where my php.exc file exists.

Comment: You need to add php to your PATH Environment Variable, Only after then you would be able to execute `php` command line from outside **php_home**.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, It works for me.
I just add my PHP installation file path in the system user variable path. Closing and opening cmd and all of the commands work perfectly.
My PHP installation path is C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.32.